# Why restrict the domain of homomorphism to decomposition group?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, class-field-theory, ramification

Let $L/K$ be a number field abelian extension. Let fix a prime ideal $p$ of $K$.

Then there is surjective homomorphism from decomposition group $D_p$ to corresponding residue field extension.

My question is, why there is no surjective hom from $Gal(L/K)$ to galois group of residue field extension ?

Comment: Nobody is claiming there is *no* surjective hom at all from the full Galois group. Focus on the actual *method* of defining the mapping from the decomposition group to the Galois group of the residue field extension, which uses in an essential way that the elements of the decomposition group fix the prime ideal you are using above $p$. Even when you say "there is a surjective homomorphism from $D_p\ldots$" you're not accounting for what the mapping actually *is*, which is crucial.  Nobody cares about whether or not there's some random surjective how, but that a *specific* hom is onto.

Comment: Here is a linear algebra analogue: for a finite-dimensional vector space $V$, there is a "natural isomorphism" from $V$ to its second dual space $V^{**}$. If someone then asked "why is there is no isomorphism from $V$ to its dual space" do you recognize that this question is missing an essential point about what was happening between $V$ and $V^{**}$?

Comment: Thank you very much, but I think $amodβ→\sigma(a)modβ$($β｜p$) induces autmorphism on residue field, even when $ \sigma \in Gal(L/K)$. This map is well defined even if we do not suppose $ \sigma (β)=β$, I think.

Comment: It is most definitely **not** well-defined. Take $K = \mathbf Q$, $L = \mathbf Q(i)$, $p = 5$, the prime ideal lying over it to be $(1+2i)$, and $\sigma$ to be complex conjugation (which is not in the decomposition group at $(1+2i)$). Then $2 \equiv i \bmod (1+2i)$, but $\sigma(2) = 2 \not\equiv -i \equiv \sigma(i) \bmod (1+2i)$. By the way, $\mathfrak p$ and $\mathfrak P$ are fraktur versions of the letters $p$ and $P$. They are *not* the Greek letter$\beta$, which is analogous to $b$. If you don't know the LaTeX code for fraktur, just write prime ideals as $P$ and $Q$ temporarily.